# Controller does not see which button was clicked

Tags: asp.net

I'm attempting to have multiple submit buttons on a MVC 4 view and then chose what action to take in the controller based on the button that is clicked. However, the controller does not recognized which button was clicked and always shows null.

What am I doing wrong?

```
//View
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<button type = "submit" name = "btn" value = "save_new" id = "SaveNew" > Save & amp; New </button>
<button type = "submit" name = "btn" value = "save_close" id = "SaveClose" > Save & amp; Close </button>
}

//Controller
public ActionResult PortalAccountMapping(PortalAccountMappingModel model, string btn)

    {
        if (btn == "save_new")
        {
            // the form was submitted using the Save&New button
        }
        else if (btn == "save_close")
        {
            // the form was submitted using the Save&Close button
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateModel(model.Grid.UpdateParams);
           return Json(model.GetRows());
        }

        return View();
    }
```

The btn value is always null.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong there - I use that approach without issues...

Comment: Do you have `[HttpPost]` above your action?

Comment: Yes, I do have [HttpPost] above the ActionResult. Clicking the buttons do cause the controller to hit the  public ActionResult PortalAccountMapping, but btn is always null.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="submit"  name="btn" value="save_new" />
```

This is used by me